# What ports need open from netbackup server to client?

Tags: networking, port, netbackup

I need to know what ports should be open from netbackup server to the server, where netbackup client is installed and vise versa?

So I need to know what network access should exist to backup and restore database to/from nb server.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

By default the NetBackup client runs on TCP port 13782.

Comment: is this enough to open ?